# Google Analytics dataLayer.push not working in a Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, promise, es6-promise, google-datalayer

I am running into a weird issue trying to trigger the `window.dataLayer.push()` when trying to utilize Google Analytics Tag Manager `dataLayer` firing logic when that call is placed inside a `Promise`. I assume this is `Promise` based due to the below logic:

Simply placing this snippet in a .js file loaded in the footer of the site, this works fine and I see it firing in my console:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

window.dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'dataLayer-initialized',
  'pageName': 'First'
});
```

I then update the file with the following:

```
const result = callGenericBackend().then((res)=>{return res});
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

window.dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'dataLayer-initialized',
  'pageName': 'First'
});

result.then((res)=>{
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'dataLayer-initialized',
      'pageName': 'Second'
    });
  })

function callGenericBackend(pageID) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      jQuery.ajax({
        type:'post',
        async: true,
        url:myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data : {pageID: pageID},
        dataType: 'json',
        error:(xhr)=>{
          console.warn('ajax error');
          reject(xhr);
          return false;
        },
        success:(data)=>{
          if (data.status === 200) {
            resolve(data);
          } else {
            reject(data);
          }
        }
      })
    })
```

The "First" continues to fire, but the "Second" is never fired. My `callGenericBackend()` simply returns a response via an `.ajax` call. What am I missing here with `Promise` logic to make this work? If I change `async: false` in `callGenericBackend()` it works, but I see this error in my console:

```
Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

Comment: I don't understand why would you need to declare `const result = callGenericBackend().then((res)=>{return res});` on the first line.

Comment: What would I use instead? Educate me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help since I don't know what data are u getting from the request and what do you want to do with that data:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

window.dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'dataLayer-initialized',
  'pageName': 'First'
});

function callGenericBackend(pageID) {
    return $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        async: true,
        url:myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data : {pageID: pageID},
        dataType: 'json',
        error:(xhr)=>{
          console.warn('ajax error');
          reject(xhr);
          return false;
        },
        success:(data)=>{
          if (data.status === 200) {
            resolve(data);
          } else {
            reject(data);
          }
        }
      })
    })
}

$.when(callGenericBackend(YOUR_ID)).done(function(response){
    //access response data here

    window.dataLayer.push({
       'event': 'dataLayer-initialized',
       'pageName': 'First'
    });
});
```

Comment: This is essentially what I have, but changing `async:` to true, which would not work.

Comment: I updated my code - If your code works with a warning when async is set to false, then try the using async: true but you need to wait for the response from the server first